# Repeatability and the Random module across different versions of OCaml

Tags: testing, random, ocaml

I've been setting up a test-suite along with advancing the application my team is writing and today I came across a problem in how I was going to test scripts that get run through our application. We allow the user to set a seed for the `Random` module to allow repeatability in results (this is very important in a scientific application), I use this in our test suite to compare the stdout/stderr from a set of scripts with 'approved' runs.

In updating those scripts I noticed that all the scripts failed on certain machines. I soon discovered this was due to the [`Random` module from version 3.12.0](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Random.html) changing the core function for generating random bits. Currently we run a number of versions of OCaml (including 3.13) across a number of environments (win32, osx, linux) and we would prefer to test against different versions of OCaml.

I would like to replace the `Random` module from 3.12.1 into our distribution to allow for consistency regardless of the version of OCaml the user is compiling against. But, the naive approach to drop the `Random` module in the source directory reports that the compiler found two files that define a module named `Random`.

Any suggestions on solving this issue? I realize I can rename `Random` to `XRandom` and then use that module to define what I need or include the standard library random module, but that would require changing every function call and allows developers to continue to (accidentally) use `Random` instead of the overloaded version. Is there a way to select a specific random module during compilation? Or maybe some other option I'm unaware of.

*EDIT*:

I just took the Random module from OCaml 3.12.1 and dropped it into my project, on compilation via OCamlbuild I got the following error message during linking (this the same error with OCaml 3.13.0+dev8, and pretty much what I expected when I did it),

```
Error: Files random.cmx and /opt/ocaml-3.12.1/lib/ocaml/stdlib.cmxa
       both define a module named Random
```

And the linking line is,

- /opt/ocaml-3.12.1/bin/ocamlopt.opt dynlink.cmxa unix.cmxa str.cmxa bigarray.cmxa -I +camlp4 camlp4fulllib.cmxa -cclib -lcside -cclib -L. -ccopt -I -ccopt /usr/lib -cclib -L. -cclib -Wl,--no-as-needed -cc gcc -cclib -llapack -cclib -lblas -cclib -lgfortran -cclib -lz -cclib -lreadline -cclib -lm -cclib '' compileFlags.cmx all_sets.cmx **random.cmx** status.cmx timer.cmx sexpr.cmx xml.cmx bitSet.cmx lz.cmx fileStream.cmx methods.cmx utl.cmx cost_matrix.cmx alphabet.cmx primes.cmx fileContents.cmx numerical.cmx version.cmx scripting.cmx libgrappa.a libgzcaml.a libzlibstubs.a libcside.a -o scripting.native

Comment: What was the exact problem you ran when you defined your own `Random` module? I've never been unable to shadow standard library modules. The restriction is that you can't (easily) use that standard library module, but that's not a problem in your case, is it?

Comment: It said two modules are named `Random`. One from `random.cmx` and one from `stdlib.cmxa`

Comment: What Ocaml versions did you observe this with? What was your linker command line? Ideally, post a small reproducible example.

Answer (score 2):

You can indeed use your own `XRandom` module, and add `module Random = XRandom` at the top of your test files.

Unfortunately, I'm afraid there is no good and clean solution to your problem ...

Comment: Thanks. I've decided that the individual developers should continue on their respective distributions, and the test slaves will all have 3.12.0+ versions installed. In this way we can pseudo maintain cross-compatibility. Of course our users will have to be informed of the caveat regarding the Random module distributed with OCaml.